# html5 canvas using sprite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to use a sprite in an html5 canvas context.

i want to drag it with my mouse.. so the displayed area changes while dragging the mouse.

It should look like a window with width: 21 and height: 90, where just a part of the sprite is  visible. when i drag the sprite downwards or upwards i want the visible part to change.

I thought i can do this with the drawImage (slice) method, but it doesnt work how i want...

Can you please help me out?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var y = 30;
            var canvas;
            var context;
            var imageHours;

            function clearClock(context) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 500);
            }

            function init(){
                canvas = document.getElementById("uhr");
                context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                imageHours = new Image();
                imageHours.src = "07.png";

                context.drawImage(imageHours, 0, y, 21, 90, 50, 50, 21, 90);

                var down = false;

                canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { down = true; }, false);  
                canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { down = false; }, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                    if(down){                   
                        if(event.layerY > 50 && event.layerY < 140){
                            y = event.layerY;           
                        }                       
                        clearClock(context);
                        context.drawImage(imageHours, 0, y, 21, 90, 50, 50, 21, 90);                        
                    }
                }, false);              
            }           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <canvas id="uhr" height="500px" width="300px"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sprite:
[image: Sprite:]

EDIT: i added a comment to my mainPost. the reason why i am trying to acomplish this like that is.. that i dont want to use a library for this.. because i want to learn such stuff... using libraries doesnt help me with learning...

Comment: Consider making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9S2Td/) next time, it'll be easier to debug it immediately then.

Comment: `But it doesn't work how I want.` Well, how do you want it?

Comment: Now when i am using the drawImage method it acts as follow:
when i slide the mouse up the list slides up, when i slide down with the mouse the digits get bigger, which i dont want...

i just want to drag the digits from top to down or otherwise round...
like a spinner, i grab at a position and from there on i drag it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. I think creating a fiddle next time would be a good idea, it helps people help you.

I think this is what you are trying to do -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mateuszwijas/4dgHa/)

Two issues I spotted:

1. Your y value is wrong, it causes the image to not display.
2. You need to update/redraw your icon on mouseup. You are setting down to false but mousemove wont redraw the icon in that case.

Edit:

I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mateuszwijas/4dgHa/6/), this should be what you want and a good starting point for your app. I'd encourage you to read up a bit more on canvas, especially on using images. The Mozzila Dev Network has a great [intro to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images), check it out for a detailed explanation for why this code works the way it does.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1. but the image is displayed?
2. ok i will have a look

mh... but your jsFiddle doesnt work very smooth.. i want to grab at a position and and move up or down and have a smooth scrolling...

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. There's no "easy" way to do this if you don't want to use a library or frame work, you'll have to do the animation yourself. Are you having trouble with the logic necessary to do something like this?

Comment: Yes absolutly... the logic is the main problem...
do you have some idea how i can teach me this stuff?

Comment: Can you host this image somewhere? I'm getting 403 forbidden in the console when it's on imgur. I think I have the solution for you. Just give me a url for the image and I'll updated the fiddle.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you very much, this helped me alot and i will read through it! :)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the things you need, you will have to build a display list. Then things will be easier.

If you don't mind using a library please check the following links. These support display list and multiple objects.

1. http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
2. http://www.kineticjs.com/

Comment: display list? what does that mean? or is it a common term which i can google for?